# How to set class and export correctly in javascript and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use`node.js` and I loaded `js` file in `ejs`

When `main.js` will be loaded,script will be functioned. while then,

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src=../javascripts/functions.js></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=../javascripts/quiz.js></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=../javascripts/main.js></script>
```

I have some issues like `Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined` in `quiz.js`

How to set `export` correctly ?

I'd like to export `quiz` class correctly. Is this issue comes from `ES6` ?

If someone has opinion,please let me know.

Thanks

`quiz.js`

```
class Quiz {
  
    constructor(quizData){
        this._quizzes = quizData.results;
        this._correctAnswersNum = 0;
    }
 
    getQuestion(index){
        return this._quizzes[index-1].question;
    }
    
}

module.exports = Quiz;
```

`main.js`

```
(()=>{
      const url = "/quiz-data";

      fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        const quiz = new Quiz(json);
        console.log("json",json);
        console.log("quiz",quiz);
        displayQuiz(quiz,1);
      });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Client-side JS does not support Node.js style [CommonJS modules](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html).

---

If you want to use modules client-side, then write [ES6 modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

---

If you just want to use shared globals, then write the code as you have it now only without the `module.exports` line.